# Why does date.getHours()%12 give you the time in 1-12 format?

Tags: javascript, time, modulus

I am not understanding why  `const hours = (date.getHours() + 11) % 12 +1;` gives the hours back in 1-12 format? I copied and pasted this code into my program but there was no explanation. Any help in explaining this would really help, thanks.

This is what I have so far...

```
const clockContainer = document.querySelector('.js-clock'),
  clockTitle = clockContainer.querySelector('h1');

function getTime() {
  const date = new Date(); //instantiate Date objet and set it to a constant variable
  const seconds = date.getSeconds(); // Gets the date objects seconds value into a const
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();
  const hours = (date.getHours() + 11) % 12 +1;
  // Ternary operator (conditional statement ? "if code block" : "else code block")
  clockTitle.innerText = `${hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : hours}:${minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}`;
}

// initialize application
function init() {
  getTime();
  setInterval(getTime, 1000); // runs getTime function every second to make the clock run
}

// call initialize function
init();
```

Comment: could you show us your code? - a complete example so we can attempt to reproduce your result.

Comment: The `.getHours()` method returns a number between 0 and 23 inclusive. Thus you definitely will never get 12 from `.getHours() % 12`.

Comment: If `0` and `23` are the accepted ranges in 24hr time, shouldn't `0` and `11` be the accepted hours in 12hr time, where `0` is twelve A.M. and P.M.? 12:42pm would just be 0:42pm in this system. It would have to be changed for display, but there's nothing incorrect about using a zero-indexed system for time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Modulus operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) returns the remainder of a division. In this case, think back to elementary school before you learned about decimal places, and would divide simply by counting, "how many times will `a` go into `b`?", and be left with a remainder that you would just forget about.

For example, 5 goes into 10 twice, so 10 divided by 5 is 2. Similarly, 5 goes into 12 twice, but not all the way... you're left with a remainder of 2. So, 12 divided by 5 is 2 with remainder 2. Therefore, 12 % 5 is 2.

You can think of a modulus operation (`n % m`) as asking, "how high **over** the closest multiple of `m` is `n`?" That's how I like to understand it in my own brain.

---

So, when you have something like `18 % 12`, you're asking, "how many times will 12 go into 18?" Answer, once, but you're not after that... you're after what's left. In this case, 6.

- "How high **over** the closest multiple of 12 is 18?"
- The closest multiple of 12 is 12 (since the next highest is 24), and 18 is 6 over 12.

Consider taking a read through of [that Wikipedia page I linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: Also note that the claim in the OP is not true.